# An Event and its Subevent are Considered Dependent?

Tags: probability, combinations

I am trying to solve a probability problem, but there are some parts of it, that I don't understand very well

The problem is a lottery game, basically it consists of picking up 6 numbers from 1 to 56, and then wait for the the raffle, where a tombola is going to withdraw
6 balls with the so called "Natural Numbers" and an extra ball called "The Additional Number"

[image]

In order to solve the problem I started doing this analysis:

> The experiment $B_G$ that refers to the process of the
> tombola selecting six balls with the "Natural Numbers" and one ball
> with the "The Additional Number" is a ***Random Experiment***
>
> The experiment $B_G$ is composed by seven smaller experiments: $B_1$,
> $B_2$, $B_3$, $B_4$, $B_5$, $B_6$, $B_a$
>
> $B_1$ is the experiment of withdrawing the 1st ball
>
> $B_2$ is the experiment of withdrawing the 2nd ball
>
> ...
>
> $B_a$ is the experiment of withdrawing the additional number
>
> The union of experiments $B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3 \cup B_4 \cup B_5 \cup B_6$  it is also consider another experiment, denoted by $B_n$
> It is also known that $B_n \cup B_a= B_G$
>
> The sample space of the experiment $B_1$ would be:
> $S_{B1}=\{1,2,3...,54,55,56\}$ and the result is going to be the event
> $E_{B1}$
> The sample space of the experiment $B_2$ would be: $S_{B2}=S_{B1}-E_{B1}$ and the result is going to be
> the event $E_{B2}$
>
> The sample space of the experiment $B_3$ would be: $S_{B3}=S_{B1}-E_{B1}-E_{B2}$ and the result is going to be the event $E_{B3}$
>
> ...
>
> The sample space of the experiment
> $B_a$ would be: $S_{Ba}=S_{B1}-E_{B1}-E_{B2}-E_{B3}-E_{B4}-E_{B5}-E_{B6}$ and the result is going to be
> the event $E_{Ba}$
>
> The sample space of the experiment $B_n$ would be:
> $S_{Bn}=\{(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3,4,5,7) ... (1,2,3,4,5,56) ... (2,3,4,5,6,7),(2,3,4,5,6,8)...  (2,3,4,5,6,56) ... (51,52,53,54,55,56)\}$
>
> and the result is going to be the event
> $E_{Bn}=(E_{B1},E_{B2},E_{B3},E_{B4},E_{B5},E_{B6})$
>
> The sample space of the experiment $B_G$ would be:
> $S_{Bn}={(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),(1,2,3,4,5,6,8)... (1,2,3,4,5,6,56) ... (2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(2,3,4,5,6,7,9) ... (2,3,4,5,6,7,56) ... (50,51,52,53,54,55,56)}$ and the result is going to be the event $E_G=(E_{Bn},E_{Ba})$
>
> The events $E_{B1}$, $E_{B2}$, $E_{B3}$, $E_{B4}$, $E_{B5}$, $E_{B6}$ are ***dependent events*** between each other since they depend on the previous balls withdrew
>
> The event $E_Bn$ is a ***dependent event*** from events  $E_{B1}$, $E_{B2}$, $E_{B3}$, $E_{B4}$, $E_{B5}$, $E_{B6}$, since their results are going to change the experiment $B_n$
>
> The event $E_{Ba}$ is a ***dependent event*** with respect $E_{Bn}$ since it depends on the previous 6 "Natural Numbers" withdrew
>
> The event $E_G$ is an ***independent event*** with respect a future event of the same type, since the whole experiment must be run from the beginning (Different Raffles)

But now, I am not exactly sure if a subevent is going to be dependent with its event, since the sample space of the event, is not going to change
depending on the result of the subevent

But also, at the same time, saying that an event doesn't depend on its subevent sounds kind of paradoxical

I feel that the clue is that we are looking for combinations, not permutations, I guess, that last one would be different
because the result of one subevent, is going to be changing the sample space of the event, I mean for example, if we obtain the number 1 at the first ball
we are going to need to remove (2,3,4,5,6,1) from the sample space, but since we are looking for combinations, it doesn't matter

I feel that there is another step I need to give with what I mean with the result of the experiment $Bn$, because I feel that $B1$,$B2$,$B3$,$B4$,$B5$,$B6$ are actually
not subevents of $Bn$, but I don't what they are then

could you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the "sample space of an event"; there is just a single sample space and all events are subsets of it. By definition, two events A and B are indepdnent if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Now if $A$ is a subevent of $B$, then $A\subset B$ so $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$. So for $A\subset B$, the condition for independence becomes $P(A)=P(A)P(B)$, and the only way this can be satisfied is if $P(A)=0$ or $P(B)=1$. Thus, an event cannot be independent of a subevent, except in the degenerate cases where the event has probability 1 or the subevent has probability 0.

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry, I wanted to say, the sample space of the experiment where the event is in.. Umm, I think there are more sample spaces since there are different experiments, the sample space of the experiment $B1$ is not the same of the experiment $BN$

Comment: So, the question should be then: an event $E_{B1}$ of the sample space of a subexperiment $B1$, can be independent from an event $E_{BN}$ of the sample space of an experiment $BN$, where $B1  \subset BN $?

Comment: when we talk about dependence, we only refer to events of the same sample space, or it can be events of another sample spaces?